# How to fit map to all markers in React Native maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps

I'm trying to position my map screen so that I can see all markers when the map renders. I've tried fitToCoordinates but I get an error that says "fitToCoordinates is not a function". I' attached a picture of my code.

[image]

Comment: How did you pass the ref of `_map`? Is it with `useRef`?

Comment: yes, const _map = React.useRef(null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it the following way.

1. The `onLayout` method is afaik not documented (I am not using it in the app I'm working on, and it relies pretty heavily on the mapView), but there's a better method to use with the map - [`onMapReady`](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md).
2. Refs have a property called `current`, which you have to access, you can't just access them as you did, because in that way it would be undefined.

So try smth like this

```
const setMapReady = () => {
  if (_map.current) {
    _map.current.fitToCoordinates([{..}, {...}]); // you can pass `animated` here and more props
  }
}

<MapView>
  ref={_map}
  ...
  onMapReady={setMapReady}
</MapView>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)